# Converting fundamental part of code from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++

I'm creating a pennies game, which has now already been created in C++, however I am having some trouble converting it to Python. It seems I can't figure out how to convert something such as this loop into Python.

```
       void penniesLeftOver(int amountOfPenniesCurrent) //Displays the amount of Pennies left to the user.
       {
         cout << "Pennies Remaining: " << amountOfPenniesCurrent; //Displays the amount of Pennies remaining.
         for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPenniesCurrent; i++)
         {
         cout << " o"; //Uses "o" to represent a Penny.
         }

      cout << "\n" << endl; //Starts a new line.
      }
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: The natural way in Python, Pythonic, is to just create a string, `print( n*"o" )`.

Comment: Do you know how to use `for` and `range` yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python you can multiply a string by an int, it will create a new string which is the initial string repeated n times.
And you can `print()` multiples things at once. Which gives:

```
def penniesLeftOver(amountOfPenniesCurrent):
    print("Pennies Remaining:", amountOfPenniesCurrent, " o"*amountOfPenniesCurrent)
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I'm extremely new to Python and forgot that you could multiply strings like this.

Comment: Welcome to Python world! You will see that there are multiple "shortcuts" like this one in Python that will save you a lot of time. But when coming from "limited" language such as C++ or Java, it takes some time getting used to such possibilities.

Comment: @Guillaume: The equivalent in C++ is `cout << string( n, 'o' )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for penny in range(amountOfPenniesCurrent):
    print(" o")
```

This is a `for` loop in Python. ("for each penny in the total number of pennies, print " o")

Comment: This will print `amountOfPenniesCurrent` new lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

while it makes more sense to modify the string beforehand so you only make one call to `print` there are other ways to accomplish your task.

`sys.stdout.write(string)` will write the variable `string` to stdout (buffered) and calling `sys.stdout.flush()` will flush that buffer to write immediately. (you can also define the buffer size)

alternatively you can use the print function's keyword argument `end=''` (which normally defaults to `\n`) to prevent a newline from being added. in python2.7 this requires calling `from __future__ import print_function`

```
>>>for i in range(10):
...    print('o', end='')
...
oooooooooo>>>
>>>for i in range(10):
...    sys.stdout.write('o')
...    sys.stdout.flush()
>>>
oooooooooo>>>
```